# Mutiple covariance matrix with high-frecuency data using R

Tags: r, arrays, bigdata

I'm working with high-frequency data which contains 2 million observations. Now, I need to calculate the daily Realized Covariance matrix, defined as:

[image]

Let  [image] be an intraday [image] prices vector and [image] the number of intraday prices

My data has the following structure:

```
Year Month Day FivMin   A   B   C   D
2000   1    1    1      1   2   3   4
2000   1    1    2      2   3   0   1
2000   1    1    3      3   4   1   2
2000   1    1    4      0   1   2   3
2000   1    2    1      1   2   3   4
2000   1    2    2      5   3   4   1
2000   1    2    3      3   0   1   2
2000   1    2    4      4   1   9   3
2000   1    3    1      1   2   3   4
2000   1    3    2      0   1   7   1
2000   1    3    3      3   4   1   2
2000   1    3    4      1   -2   2   3
2000   1    4    1      0   2   3   4
2000   1    4    2      2   1   4   1
2000   1    4    3      3   0   1   2
2000   1    4    4      0   2   2   3
2000   1    5    1      1   2   3   4
2000   1    5    2      2   3   4   1
2000   1    5    3      0   -1   1   2
2000   1    5    4      9   1   2   3
```

Variables A, B, C, and D represent prices recorded each five minutes. So my first idea is to use `group_by` with the variables Year, Month, and Day in order to create the [image] matrix. After this, I need to calculate the Realized Cov for each day.

For example, for the first day my Realized Cov would be:

[image]

this operation has to be repeated every day. I do not if there is a package for this problem or not. Maybe, it is better to use a loop.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: can you put a dput command to your dataframe? So that anyone can reproduce your data and help you. Like dput(df). copy and paste the output

Comment: I'm not familiar with the calculation for Realized Covariance - could you provide a definition (or explain how you calculated the values in the table)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a base R solution using `split` (for grouping) + `tcrossprod` (for cov matrix)

```
res <- lapply(split(df,df[c("Year","Month","Day")]), 
              function(x) tcrossprod(t(x[c("A","B","C","D")])))
```

such that

```
> res
$`2000.1.1`
   A  B  C  D
A 14 20  6 12
B 20 30 12 22
C  6 12 14 20
D 12 22 20 30

$`2000.1.2`
   A  B   C  D
A 51 21  62 27
B 21 14  27 14
C 62 27 107 45
D 27 14  45 30

$`2000.1.3`
   A  B  C  D
A 11 12  8 13
B 12 25 13 11
C  8 13 63 27
D 13 11 27 30

$`2000.1.4`
   A  B  C  D
A 13  2 11  8
B  2  9 14 15
C 11 14 30 24
D  8 15 24 30

$`2000.1.5`
   A  B  C  D
A 86 17 29 33
B 17 15 19 12
C 29 19 30 24
D 33 12 24 30
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(Year = c(2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 
2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L, 2000L), Month = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), Day = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), FivMin = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), A = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 0L, 3L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 9L), B = c(2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 
-2L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 2L, 2L, 3L, -1L, 1L), C = c(3L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 3L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L
), D = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```